# Spring Data MongoDB Annotation @CreatedDate isn't working, when ID is assigned manually

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to use auditing to save `dateCreated` and `dateUpdated` in my objects, but since I set `ID` manually, there's some additional work.

Following Oliver Gierke's suggestion in [DATAMONGO-946](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-946)
I'm trying to figure out how to correctly implement it.

As original poster in Jira task above, I've downloaded example from here https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mongodb.git and modified it a bit:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable;

import java.util.Date;

public class Customer implements Persistable<String> {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private boolean persisted;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public void setPersisted(boolean persisted) {
        this.persisted = persisted;
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return !persisted;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Customer[id=%s, createdDate=%s, lastModifiedDate=%s, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']",
                id, createdDate, lastModifiedDate, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

and

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.EnableMongoAuditing;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        repository.deleteAll();

        // create a customer
        Customer c = new Customer("Alice", "Smith");
        c.setId("test_id");

        // save a customer
        repository.save(c);

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // create another customer with same id
        c = new Customer("Bob", "Smith");
        c.setId("test_id");
        c.setPersisted(true);
        repository.save(c);

        // fetch all customers
        System.out.println("Customers found with findAll():");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        for (Customer customer : repository.findAll()) {
            System.out.println(customer);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and a result of execution is this:

```
Customers found with findAll():
-------------------------------
Customer[id=test_id, createdDate=Wed Feb 24 00:43:47 WITA 2016, lastModifiedDate=Wed Feb 24 00:43:47 WITA 2016, firstName='Alice', lastName='Smith']

Customers found with findAll():
-------------------------------
Customer[id=test_id, createdDate=null, lastModifiedDate=Wed Feb 24 00:43:47 WITA 2016, firstName='Bob', lastName='Smith']
```

`createdDate` becomes `null` after object update.

What am I missing here? And how to correctly implement `Persistable` to make auditing work properly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code is working as expected. After you've implemented `Persistable` you can see that `@CreatedDate` annotation is working.

Sure that `createdDate` is `null` on the second call of `save` because the object already exists in the database and you updated it with `createdDate = null`. As you can see from the documentation for `@CreatedDate`:

> @CreatedDate annotation. This identifies the field whose value is set
>   when the entity is persisted to the database for the first time.

So not to overwrite your `createdDate` with `null` on the second call you should retrieve your customer from the database with `c = repository.findOne("test_id");` and then update it.

Comment: Thank you, Orest. Looks like it is the way you describe it. But it means that I need to manage the field myself. Why do i need annotation then? Isn't it created to automatically manage these fields? Perhaps only when ID is automatically generated as well.

Comment: So @CreatedDate works as expected it automatically generate createdDate for you on the first save and on the second time customer already exists in database with that id. It would be wrong if new createdDate would be generated on second save. To update customer as I said you should first get it from database.

Comment: Yes, of course. For next update there is `@LastModifiedDate`, which is set automatically on update. I just thought that a field marked with `@CreatedDate` would automatically be skipped on update. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I agree with and_rew. I expected the field annotationed with @CreatedDate to be set with the initial insert date, and to keep that value on subsequent updates. Why the hell would I want the creation date to be removed on updates? The whole point of auditing is to keep that information.

Comment: You're trying to create a new object with same ID and expect to get creation date from old object. You have two options here: 1. get object by id, update some fields and then save it. 2. Write a method to update only field that you need. I think the best will second option to make sure you're not overriding some fields

Comment: Is there anyway I can manually set the value using a setter for a field annotated by LastModifiedDate or CreatedDate ?

Comment: @Echo if you want manually set values you don't need to use those annotations.

Comment: @Orest , there is one case in which I need to manually set this field . Is there anyway I can do it ?

Comment: @Echo something like this ? http://ufasoli.blogspot.com/2017/01/spring-data-force-version-and.html

Comment: The opposite infact . Here, the user has used "auditingHandler.markModified(contact)" to mark the object to be modified even when it is not. I want to "unmark" it if that is possible.

Comment: @Echo ah yes sorry. There should be some possibility I guess, but don't know for sure.

Comment: this is annoying for kotlin data classes. When I do an update I create a new object with the same id.

Answer (score 16):

Add `@EnableMongoAuditing` to the main method in your spring boot application.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest solution is to add a version property (annotated with @Version) to your Customer class and leave it uninitialized. this will assign the value of 0 to any newly created object which in turn tells spring that this is a new object.

```
  @Version private Long version;
```

Note: that this version will be automatically incremented upon each modifications on this object

Comment: Thanks! It helps me! Without version field it doesn't init `createdDate` fields